# itext 2.1.3 - HTMLWorker.parseToList(Reader reader, StyleSheet style) throwing NullPointerException

Tags: pdf-generation, itext

We have been using the method to generate PDF from HTML string. However, it has started throwing `NullPointerException` on one of our servers which is quite unprecedented. We have tried changing the jar but all in vain.

```
StyleSheet styles = getDefaultStyleSheet(); //Defined below
String htmlString ; //The string is fine as the same method is creating PDF on our other servers

ArrayList<Element> p = HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(htmlString), styles);

//method that returns stylesheet
private StyleSheet getDefaultStyleSheet() {
    StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
    styles.loadTagStyle("td", "size", "10px");
    styles.loadTagStyle("p", "leading", "12f");
    return styles;
}
```

The flow works fine upto this method, however throws exception as soon as it crosses the method. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the exact stacktrace? Where is the exception actually thrown from? Also, note that it's not recommended to use old versions of iText, since they show some legal and technical issues : http://lowagie.com/iText2

Comment: The stack trace is :

2013-06-19 09:43:25,976 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-8180-69) makePDF 1com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet@2e312fec
2013-06-19 09:43:25,976 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8180-69) java.lang.NullPointerException
2013-06-19 09:43:25,976 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-8180-69) java.lang.NullPointerException

The exception occurs on call to HTMLWorker.parseToList method.

Answer (score 0):

`<Hr>` tags will cause NullPointer/NullReference Exception in HTMLWorker.

Comment: A server restart solved the problem. However, the result is unknown.